# IBM Filenet and Content Navigator - Editing Choice List

Tags: filenet, filenet-content-engine, ibm-content-navigator

IBM FileNet And IBM Content Navigator Problem
how to Modify (FileNet Content Engine) Choice List from Content Navigator
as I want to add new values or delete or Edit Exist Value ?

Answer (score 1):

use ACCE or FEM to modify Choice List. 
Also custom tools are available (via API)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to edit Choise List from ICN you can try to create own plug-in to make it through API (you can find widget in ACCE and try to embed it in ICN), and you should have privelegies to modify choise list.

Answer (score 0):

If your choice lists are prone to change, then your best design decision would be not to use CE choice lists, rather, create these property templates as string fields, and fill them using EDS.

For the EDS, you can always use custom database to read the lookup data for the choice lists from, this database you can manage then using your RDBMS enginer interface or through a custom interface you build (and you can then include this custom interface inside the navigator using an iFrame as a feature).